# how to create/draw dynamic shapes in flex 4

Tags: flex4, shapes

Im a new bee in flex , I want to draw different dynamic shapes.. a sample url is given below.

Any suggestion would be appreciated..

http://www.onlinelabels.com/maestro-label-design-software.htm

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the drawing API to dynamically draw shapes.

Here is a good resource to get you started [Using ActionScript 3 drawing commands](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/drawing_commands_as3.html)

You can also use the new spark primitives (such as Rect) in Flex 4 to generate some fairly sophisticated shapes with a bit of creativity.

Also, not a a run time dynamic option but you can do just about anything using FXG. Build your shapes in Illustrator CS5 or Flash CS5 and export as FXG and then import into Flex 4.